# Сохранение и восстановление состояния фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment

Имеется 5 фрагментов со своей разметкой, отображаются они в FrameView. Каждый фрагмент может быть создан несколько раз, соответственно данные в них будут разные. Требуется, чтобы приложение умело сохранять состояние каждого фрагмента, чтобы имелась возможность переключаться между ними  в любом направлении, т.е. условно образовался стек из 8 фрагментов, нужно иметь возможность переключится, например, с 7-го на 2-й, что-то в нем поменять и вернуться обратно.

Сейчас делаю так:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(idQuestion)) != null){
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(idQuestion));
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameFragment, fragment).commit();
        }
        else {

        switch (typeQuestion){
                case 0:
                    fragment = new FragmentTestOneType();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new FragmentTestTwoType();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new FragmentTestThreeType();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new FragmentTestFourType();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fragment = new FragmentTestFiveType();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FormTotalTest.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    fragment = new FragmentCheckTest();
                    break;
            }
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameFragment, fragment, String.valueOf(idQuestion));
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Но программа падает с такой ошибкой:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: FragmentTestTwoType{41fe8ab8 #1 id=0x7f0a0051 1}
```

Насколько я понимаю, фрагмент `FragmentTestTwoType` уже добавлен. 
Существует ли способ, как можно грамотно организовать переходы между фрагментами?

Comment: > фрагмент FragmentTestTwoType уже добавлен.    

Нет, это значит, что фрагмент с таким тегом уже добавлен. Тег должен быть уникальным

Comment: Прошел дебагером по коду, падает на этой строке:

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameFragment, fragment)

Посоветуйте, как можно выйти из данной ситуации.
Пробовал по-разному возвращаться в предыдущему фрагменту, но результата это не дало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фрагмент уже добавлен (в `else {}`), а вы пытаетесь выполнить на нем `replace()`, в этом и ошибка.
Попробуйте использовать не `replace()`, а `FragmentTransaction.show()/hide()` для всех фрагментов. Посмотрите примеры `FragmentHideShow.java` и `FragmentMenu.java` в `android-sdk-linux/samples/android-22/legacy/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app`.

Можно ещё посмотреть, как реализован класс `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Там используются не `hide()/show()`, а `attach()/detach()`. Т.е. фрагменты отцепляются от UI, но при этом не удаляются из менеджера фрагментов.